# HSTS exclude specific subdomain with "includeSubdomains"

Tags: nginx, https, http-headers

I'm using HSTS with this header on my website:

```
 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
```

This works as intended and forces the browser to redirect all http connections to https.

In the documentation at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1.2 I did not find a way to exclude specified subdomains!

I already tried to add `max-age=0` for the subdomain, but it does not overwrite `includeSubDomains`

Is it possible to exclude subdomains from the `includeSubDomains` rule?
Or is the only way to remove this rule and just use the HSTS header for some websites?
PS: My webserver is NGINX and I tested the behaviour with firefox and chrome.

Comment: No way. Either it works for all subdomains or you have to set it for every subdomain explicitly. Or move your exception to completely unrelated domain

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I will just send the header without includeSubdomains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No:

I think one of the points of `includeSubdomains` is to ensure that it's not possible for an attacker to hijack cookies etc. by forcing end user to load a subdomain over plain http and then them. If there was even one exception to `includeSubdomains` then it would be useless (assuming it's possible for the attacker to figure out what the exception is).